# How to generate random numbers with a normal distribution based on endpoints in excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to generate random numbers with a normal distribution in excel. What I have, though, are two endpoints, which I would like to be 3 standard deviations away from the mean. How can I write a formula such that the cell creates a normal distribution with only the end points as the available input information?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914247/how-to-generate-random-numbers-within-a-normal-distribution-using-excel

Comment: @ScottCraner this question does not provide an answer to mine.

Comment: Why (attempt to) use Excel for this? It's the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If max is the larger of the endpoints and min is the smaller,
norm.inv(rand(), (max+min)/2, (max-min)/6) should produce a random number in a normal distribution.  So dragging that formula down should produce a collection of values with the desired distribution.